# Get SSID when WIFI is connected

Tags: android, wifi, ssid

I'm trying to get the SSID of the WIFI network when my android device is connected to WIFI.

I've registered a BroadcastReceiver listening for `android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE` . I get the notification when WIFI is disconnected or reconnected. Unfortunately, I can't get the network's SSID.

I'm using the following code to find the SSID:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

Instead of the SSID, I get the string [`<unknown ssid>`](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43336) back.

These are the permissions in the manifest (I've added ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE just to check, I don't actually need it)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Why does this happen? How can I get the actual SSID? Is the broadcast fired to early, before the connection is established? Is there another broadcast I should listen to? I'm only interested in WIFI connections, not 3G connections.

Update: I just checked, `wifiInfo.getBSSID()` returns null.

Comment: Interesting, the docs state you should receive `null` from `getSSID()` if the connection is not available, so I don't think it's a connection problem.  Just wondering, what is the SSID of the network you're testing on?

Comment: What is the detailed state and suplicant state?

Comment: @Ben S, check the link I supplied in the question, <unknown ssid> is Android 4.2's behavior, and possibly newer versions as well. It's an Android bug.

Comment: Try this SO answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977395/on-oreo-8-1-0-not-getting-the-correct-wifi-ssid-its-showing-unknown-ssid-t/51518480#51518480

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I listen for WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION in a broadcast receiver

```
if (WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
    NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra (WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI == netInfo.getType ()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I check for `netInfo.isConnected()`. Then I am able to use

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid  = info.getSSID();
```

**UPDATE**

From android 8.0 onwards we wont be getting SSID of the connected network unless location services are enabled and your app has the permission to access it.

Comment: @Eric : would you please share full code with broadcast reciever as well.

Comment: I did share it in the first code block. "action" comes from the broadcast receiver's received intent.

Comment: You should change `WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);` to `WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);` Because WiFiManager must use Application Context (not Activity Context), otherwise a memory leak can occur.

Comment: Are you sure this works on Android 8 even with GPS turned on?  NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED is not in the list of [implicit broadcast exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), so I don't think the system will call your BroadcastReceiver any longer.

Comment: That UPDATE is important! Even with all the right permissions, you will still get an unknown SSID until GPS is actually turned on! (Tested only on Android 9)

Comment: Giving COARSE location permission is enough. There is no need to turn on GPS.

Comment: Android 8.0  solution see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391836/2447726

Comment: I wonder if it's the GPS that needs to be turned on, or if it's enough to have Location Services enabled (and corresponding permissions granted, of course).

Answer (score 60):

Starting with Android 8.1 (API 27), apps must be granted the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` (or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`) permission in order to obtain results from `WifiInfo.getSSID()` or `WifiInfo.getBSSID()`. Apps that target API 29 or higher (Android 10) must be granted `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

This permission is also needed to obtain results from `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo()` and `WifiManager.getScanResults()` although it is not clear if this is new in 8.1 or was required previously.

[Source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/e42dd31b3f656f33be99fd37f26e07557d163b54#diff-87dc47bf75c6bbb0d746d9671c2aedf6): "BSSID/SSID can be used to deduce location, so require the same
location permissions for access to these WifiInfo fields
requested using WifiManager.getConnectionInfo() as for
WifiManager.getScanResults()."

Comment: Is it just me or does Android P DP2 enforce this even if you're targeting a low SDK?

Comment: It appears that 8.1+ devices require this irrespective of target sdk

Comment: Works on Android P beta as well

Comment: + for citation on why it requires location permission.

Answer (score 44):

### If you don't want to make Broadcast Receiver then simple try

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo;

wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
    ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
}
```

Remember every time user disconnect or connect to new SSID or any wifi state change then you need to initialize WifiInfo i.e `wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();`

Comment: This looks oh so much better than the accepted answer. Why listen to net state changes when there might actually be none at the specific run-time of our necessity to check this information (SSID of connected network)? I'm assuming though, there might be the possibility of WifiInfo being null because of the documentation on getConnectionInfo, so guard checks are due IMHO.

Comment: It should be WifiManager not WiFiManager

Comment: Works. Just need to set permissions : INTERNET, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE , and location permission: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 16):

I found interesting solution to get SSID of currently connected Wifi AP.
You simply need to use iterate `WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()` and find configuration with specific `WifiInfo.getNetworkId()`

My example

in Broadcast receiver with action `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`
I'm getting current connection state from intent

```
NetworkInfo nwInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
nwInfo.getState()
```

If `NetworkInfo.getState` is equal to `NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED` then i can get current WifiInfo object

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
```

And after that

```
public String findSSIDForWifiInfo(WifiManager manager, WifiInfo wifiInfo) {

    List<WifiConfiguration> listOfConfigurations = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    for (int index = 0; index < listOfConfigurations.size(); index++) {
        WifiConfiguration configuration = listOfConfigurations.get(index);
        if (configuration.networkId == wifiInfo.getNetworkId()) {
            return configuration.SSID;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And very important thing this method **doesn't require Location nor Location 
Permisions**

**In API29 Google redesigned Wifi API so this solution is outdated for Android 10.**

Comment: works great; I skipped all your things/description before receiving wifiInfo (still had this + the manager before). wondering whether this will change with android 9

Comment: You're welcome. I tested this solution in "Pie" and it still working

Comment: this is not working in android Q without location permission, getConfiguredNetworks is returning empty list and getNetworkId is returning -1. It is working with location permission.

Comment: WifiConfiguration is deprecated in API 29 = Android 10

Comment: You're right, but for backward compatibility purposes it can be useful. Thanks for your feadback

Answer (score 5):

In Android 8.1 it is must to turned Location on to get SSID, if not you can get connection state but not SSID

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = null;
if (wifiManager != null) 
wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
 String ssid = null;
if (wifiInfo != null) 
ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID(); /*you will get SSID <unknown ssid> if location turned off*/
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a follow up to the answer given by @EricWoodruff.

You could use `netInfo`'s `getExtraInfo()` to get wifi SSID.

```
if (WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals (action)) {
    NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra (WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI == netInfo.getType ()) {
        String ssid = info.getExtraInfo()
        Log.d(TAG, "WiFi SSID: " + ssid)
    }
}
```

If you are not using BroadcastReceiver check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977395/on-oreo-8-1-0-not-getting-the-correct-wifi-ssid-its-showing-unknown-ssid-t/51518480#51518480) answer to get SSID using `Context`

This is tested on Android Oreo 8.1.0

Comment: This doesn't work for me on 9.0, getExtraInfo() returs null

Answer (score 4):

For me it only worked when I set the permission on the phone itself (settings -> app permissions -> location always on).

Answer (score 3):

Answer In Kotlin
Give Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



 private fun getCurrentNetworkDetail() {
    val connManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
    if (networkInfo.isConnected) {
        val wifiManager =
            context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        val connectionInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
        if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.ssid)) {
            Log.e("ssid", connectionInfo.ssid)
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.e("ssid", "No Connection")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns the service set identifier (SSID) of the current 802.11 network.
If the SSID can be decoded as UTF-8, it will be returned surrounded by double quotation marks. Otherwise, it is returned as a string of hex digits. The SSID may be WifiManager.UNKNOWN_SSID, if there is no network currently connected or if the caller has insufficient permissions to access the SSID.
Prior to Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1, this method always returned the SSID with no quotes around it.
Returns:
the SSID.

```
public String getSSID() {
    if (mWifiSsid != null) {
        String unicode = mWifiSsid.toString();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(unicode)) {
            return "\"" + unicode + "\"";
        } else {
            String hex = mWifiSsid.getHexString();
            return (hex != null) ? hex : WifiManager.UNKNOWN_SSID;
        }
    }
    return WifiManager.UNKNOWN_SSID;
}
```

it should be 'insufficient permissions'.
Below is the permissions of my demo, test on Android 9, it's ok. you can add all of them for judging the reason：

Answer (score 0):

According to the explanation of the official document, **on Android 10+(API 29 and higher)**, declaring `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or
`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions is not enough.

**1. For foreground location:**

You also need to declare a `foregroundServiceType` of `location` in your Service to use foreground location.

```
<service
    android:name="MyNavigationService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="location" ... >
    <!-- Any inner elements would go here. -->
</service>
```

Or if your code running in the Activity, the activity should be visible to the user.

**2. For background location:**

You should declare the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission in your app's manifest in order to request background location access at runtime.

> Note: The Google Play Store has a location policy concerning device
> location, restricting background location access to apps that need it
> for their core functionality and meet related policy requirements.

Official document:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-permissions

Answer (score -3):

Android 9 SSID showing NULL values use this code..

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            wifiInfo.getSSID();
            String name = networkInfo.getExtraInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
            return ssid.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
        }
```

Comment: please consider adding some explanation what your code is doing and why it is correct

Comment: NetworkInfo.isConnected and getExtraInfo is depreacted in API 28 so it doesn't work in Android 9