# Is it possible to create a chat application for people connecting to the same wifi?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

If it is possible, is there any router can block this feature to work?
We are currently planning to create a project for our class in this quarter but we are not sure if this is always able to work through our university wifi. It seems that our university wifi needs some license and different from normal wifi system at home.

Comment: Well... Have you tried it...?

Comment: Create for different wifi after that post question how to constraint it for same wifi

Comment: You can check their wifi SSID when they run app.
Like: if(wifi_ssid.equals("ADSDSD")) then connect();
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391395/get-ssid-when-wifi-is-connected

Comment: @Luke Park It's week 1 and we are researching about what technologies to use to how could it works... So not tried yet

Comment: @TruongHieu So maybe we can use GPS information to find a possible group of people then use ssid to further verify if they actually connect to the same wifi? Sounds a good way to do!

Comment: I dont think GPS information is good in this case. I mean if you can check what wifi name they are connected in, you can give or prevent their connection to your chat room.

Comment: `Is it possible to create a chat application for people connecting to the same wifi?`. Of course. Of course. But a router can block many things. Where are you thinking about that it would not work?

Comment: @greenapps, what does a router have to do with users on the same LAN?  Routers route _between_ LANs, not on the same LAN.

Comment: I think routers can do both. But for the problem we talk about routing traffic between devices in one LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use BSSID to identify the group of users.