# Getting WiFi name in Android 8.1?

Tags: android

I want to get the name of connected WiFi in Android 8.1. When I get the SSID it returns "unknown ssid". Some answers on Stack-overflow say to get Location permissions. I even did that, but the issue persists.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return getString(R.string.grant_location_permission_wifi_name)
        }
    }
    val wifiInfo = mWifiManager.connectionInfo
    return wifiInfo.ssid
```

Comment: Have you tried the permissions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847947/9356258

Comment: @NielsNet Yes I have tried that answer as well.

Comment: @SharadKhanna its not a duplicate. Read questions carefully, this is specifically for 8.1!

Comment: But there is a connection?

Comment: @NielsNet Yes, I am able to get the WiFi strength perfectly, but not the name!

Comment: its happening to me as well on a API 27 device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Oreo (8.1.0) not getting the correct Wifi SSID. It's showing <unknown ssid> though it is connected to a wifi with SSID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977395/on-oreo-8-1-0-not-getting-the-correct-wifi-ssid-its-showing-unknown-ssid-t)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your GPS is also switched on. It doesn't work if the GPS is off.