# Get WiFi SSID in Android Module

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an Android Module and get WiFi SSID inside the module.

However, the

`getApplicationContext()`   in

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();
String ssid  = info.getSSID();
```

function doesn't work inside the module.

How can I get the WiFi SSID string in an Android Module?

Comment: see [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391836/5919568 ]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method in your android module to initialize the `context`. Then call that method from your `main android application`, better place to initialize the module context is **Application#onCreate**.