# How to get WIFI SSID in Android 10.0?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

There's no problem getting SSID in Android 9.0&8.0
but I can't get SSID in Android 10.0(Q).
How should I do? and Where is the document links about wifi in android 10.0? I tried to find the document but I couldn't find it.

There's no problem getting SSID in Android 9.0&8.0

```
WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
assert mWifiManager != null;
WifiInfo info = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
return info.getSSID();
```

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
assert connManager != null;
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
     if (networkInfo.getExtraInfo() != null) {
        return networkInfo.getExtraInfo().replace("\"", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It want be get.check original post

> From android 8.0 onwards we wont be getting SSID of the connected
>   network unless GPS is turned on.

[Get SSID when WIFI is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391395/get-ssid-when-wifi-is-connected)

```
WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
assert mWifiManager != null;
WifiInfo info = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
return info.getSSID();
```

Comment: it does not work with Android 10 (Q). The wifi name of OS is still showing event without GPS

Comment: This did not work at first but then I requested permissions from the user before calling this and it finally worked. I don't recall which particular permission made this finally work though.