# How To Make App Only Run On Specific WiFi

Tags: android

Is there any way to make an app can only run if connected to a certain network? For example I have a wifi network named XYZ and I want the app only run if connected to that network (It's an attendant checker app). Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this [check SSID of connected WIFI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391836/9976418).

You can check network ssid and based on this continue or stop your application

Comment: Yeah, Thank You!